# kotlin: call higher-order function with multiple lambdas

Tags: android, lambda, kotlin, higher-order-functions

Is it possible to call a function with multiple lambda functions?

If so, how can I invoke the following function?

```
fun post(path: String, 
         params: JSONObject, 
         completionHandler: (response: JSONObject?) -> Unit, 
         errorCompletionHandler: (error: VolleyError?) -> Unit
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would define the lambdas as shown below. You can assign them to variables to make the code more readable. This becomes especially handy if you lambda become bigger.

```
val completionHandler: (JSONObject?) -> Unit = { response -> 
    // ...
}

val errorCompletionHandler: (VolleyError?) -> Unit = { error -> 
    // ...
}

post("/path", jsonObject, completionHandler, errorCompletionHandler)
```

Or you can define functions which you pass using a reference:

```
fun errorCompletionHandler(error: VolleyError?) {}
fun completionHandler(response: JSONObject?) {}

post("/path", jsonObject, ::completionHandler, ::errorCompletionHandler)
```

Notice that `Unit` can be ommitted here because it is the implicit return type if nothing else was specified.

Comment: You could also use named parameters for readability without suggesting lambdas will be used more than once: `post("/path", jsonObject,\ncompletionHandler = { response->...},\nerrorCompletionHandler = ...)` (`\n` stands for line break).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can have as many lambdas as you like. The shown `post` can be invoked as follows:

```
post("/a", "json", {response-> println(response) }, { error-> println(error)})
```

It's also possible to lift the last lambda out of the parentheses as described in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#higher-order-functions):

> In Kotlin, there is a convention that if the last parameter to a function is a function, and you're passing a lambda expression as the corresponding argument, you can specify it outside of parentheses.

Applied to your code, this means:

```
post("/a", "json", { response -> println(response) }) { error ->
    println(error)
}
```